# meaning of "ACCURACY PERCENT of the time"

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is part of a news article about an AI program that reads CT scans for diagnosis. I don't understand the meaning of 'of the time' at the end, which seems to be an error or possibly an unnecessary phrase.
I guess the last sentence in the following paragraph means Sybil was able to predict whether a person will develop lung cancer within a coming year with at most 94% accuracy.

> Meet Sybil, an artificial intelligence program. “We developed Sybil,
> an algorithm that is able to tell who might be at risk for lung cancer
> one, three, five years down the road.” Sybil could accurately predict
> whether a person will develop lung cancer in the next year up to 94%
> **of the time**.

Comment: "of the time" is mainly used in the set phrase "most of the time", meaning that something is true more often than not.  Using it with a percentage, as above, is grammatically correct but unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Of the time," is a common phrase, based on the idea that "times" means *multiple instances*. We can try something once, or a second *time*, or many *times*.

- "It works 94% of all the times Sybil was tested."
- "She learned to multiply by memorizing the times tables."
- "Four times out of ten flips the coin landed heads-up."
- Writing "5 + 5 + 5 = 20," we say "Three *times* five equals twenty."

But memorizing, "These are the times that try men's souls," might be a Paine.

Comment: Haha. Cruel pun in an English learner's forum. :p

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I wonder if the sentence can be rephrased like "Sybil could accurately predict whether a person will develop lung cancer in the next year up to 94% of the time when Sybil was asked about his/her case."

Comment: You could paraphrase it that way, though it would be overlong. Also, the colloquial way to state that would be, "up to 94% of the times that Sybil was asked." The plural would be more natural, here, I believe.

Comment: A better paraphrase is the one at the end of the OP itself.